# Cut / clear selected region of pdf using Preview

Tags: preview

As shown in the screenshot I have selected a rectangular region. I want to clear that section. None of the menu/toolbar items are apt for this task.  Is there a workaround?

[image]

**Update** It was suggested to use the Tools|Annotation|Text and put a white background text . However I see no way to configure the text - including customizing the font, fg/bg color, transparency, etc.  How to do so?  See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Clarification: my suggestion was to use the Tools Menu item to access the Annotate sub-menu and from there select Text- this places a text block overlay on your document that you can then position by grabbing and dragging any edge of the block & resize by grabbing & dragging any of the square "handles" at the corners & centers of each side.

Answer (score 1):

The only substitute for "clearing" a section in a pdf that is not editable is to use the Tools: Annotate: Text command and make the fill color of the text block white. This will cover what's behind it and you can type in whatever text you wish to replace what is covered.

Comment: I did try that before but there are no options *at all* here. I can not set the font, the transparency is set to 100%, etc.  So apparently you know something I do not in terms of where to find configuration for the Text annotation.

Comment: Why use a text block when you could use a shape? Use a box with white line and white fill?